# Rails: PG::ConnectionBad (connection is closed)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql

I'm using native query in Rails (because my query is complicated, and I don't think it can express in `ActiveRecord`). So here is how I try:

```
get  do
  connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection
  connection.prepare('order_statistic', @@sql)
  data = connection.exec_prepared('order_statistic', [params[:id]])
  connection.close()
  data
end
```

This code run successfully for first time. But second time, It will throw exception. (I'm using PostgresSQL)

> PG::ConnectionBad (connection is closed)

If I remove line `connection.close`. I will meet another exception:

> PG::DuplicatePstatement (ERROR:  prepared statement "order_statistic"
>   already exists

Please help me how to use raw query correctly.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do raw query you may follow this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(%{YOUR QUERY HERE})
```

The reason in your code is you already close connection to database, so you can't do further query, to reconnect the db you can call `reconnect!` like:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reconnect!
```

But I won't recommend you do it, rails already help you handle it, don't do it yourself, let use my first suggestion to complete all raw query!